# keras and keras-applications dependencies

Tags: python, keras, dependencies

I am trying to install keras on a Windows pc (procedure has to be done offline) I have downloaded (through another pc then transfered to this one) wheels for both modules and I am trying to install them by pip install . However, keras needs keras-applications installed and keras-applications needs keras installed, and pip install command fails when my computer tries to connect to internet for missing dependencies. Is there a way to work this through?

EDIT : I am working with python 2.7.15

Comment: which python version are you working with?

Comment: python version 2.7.15

Comment: well i can suggest ... if you are not using pip ... which certainly does a pre check for dependencies. Now i wud suggest that copy same file structure and paste it in /libs folder ... so you would see all the libraries in a folder .... try copying folder structure from another machine .... try once ... if you are still not able to get it ... so try if you can clone it from github

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I was using pip - and managed to solve my problem adding --find-links argument.

Comment: thats cool then..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I did manage to solve it this way :

I passed --find-links argument in this way :

```
pip install --find-links C:\mdependency_packages_path\ C:\package_to_install_path
```